# How to import XML to database?

Tags: c#, xml, sqlite

I exported to XML from SQLite in C#. I need to import this XML to an empty SQLite database.I also need to verify contents while inserting. My XML:

```
<root>
    <name1>
        <names>
           <id>5</id>
           <class>space</class>
           <from>Germany</from>
           <to>France</to>
           <through>
              <via>
                   <id>7</id>
                   <route>Vienna<route>
               </via>
           </through>           
        </names>
        <mynames3>Black</mynames3>
        <mynames4>Hawkins</mynames4>
    </name1>
    <name2>
      <newNames>
          <id>8</id>
          <path>Road</path>
          <dest>USA</dest>
          <through>
              <route1>
                  <id>5</id>
                  <naviagte>Britain</naviagte>
                  <naviagte2>Holland</naviagte2>
                  <naviagting2>
                      <naviagtes2>
                            <naviagte5>France</naviagte5>
                            <naviagte6>US</naviagte6>
                            <naviagte7>Canada</naviagte7>
                       <naviagtes2>
                  </naviagting2>
                  <naviagte11>Russia</naviagte11>
                  <naviagte12>Poland</naviagte12>
              </route1>
              <route1>
                  <id>2</id>
                  <naviagte>Canada</naviagte>
              </route1>
          </through>              
      </newNames>
    </name2>
    <name3>H2V3</name3>
    <name4>H5V8</name4>
</root>
```

How to do so ? I tried:

```
SqliteConnection sqlCon = new SqliteConnection("Data Source=" + dataPath + "/Empty.db3");
            sqlCon.Open();
            SqliteCommand sqlCmd = new SqliteCommand(sqlCon);

            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds.ReadXml(Path.Combine(syncPath, tableName + "_4.xml"), XmlReadMode.ReadSchema);
            foreach(DataTable dt in ds.Tables)
            {
                //Get field names
                string sqlString = "INSERT into " + tableName + " (";
                string valString = "";
                var sqlParams = new string[dt.Rows[0].ItemArray.Count()];
                int count = 0;
                foreach(DataColumn dc in dt.Columns)
                {
                    sqlString += dc.ColumnName + ", ";
                    valString += "@" + dc.ColumnName + ", ";
                    sqlParams[count] = "@" + dc.ColumnName;
                    count++;
                }
                valString = valString.Substring(0, valString.Length - 2);
                sqlString = sqlString.Substring(0, sqlString.Length - 2) + ") VALUES (" + valString + ")";

                sqlCmd.CommandText = sqlString;
                foreach(DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < dr.ItemArray.Count(); i++) 
                    {
                        sqlCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(sqlParams[i], dr.ItemArray[i] ?? DBNull.Value);
                    }

                    sqlCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                }
            }
```

Comment: This looks like homework.  The storing into the database is simple.  The hard part is to parse the xml file.  The best was is to use Xml Linq.  You can use statements like List<XElement> naviagtes = doc.Descendants().Where(x => (x.Name.LocalName).StartsWith("naviagte)).ToList().  You also may need to use recursion.

Answer (score 1):

First generate the C# classes using the XML2CSharp website. De-serialise into this generated class. Next create the classes to store the de-serialised data into. Create these as tables. Finally copy from de-serialised data into SQLite container classes and then store those classes:

```
public static List<Jobs> JobData = new List<Jobs>();

var s = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Jobs));
var r = new StreamReader(xmlFilename);
JobData.Add((Jobs)s.Deserialize(r));
r.Close();
```

Comment: Is it this [xmltocsharp](https://xmltocsharp.azurewebsites.net/)-page?